# Сравнение первого символа в переменной. php

Tags: php, сравнение

Всем привет.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить в переменной первый символ?
имеем:
$number=8-950-xxxxxxxx;

нужно создать условие, если первый символ 8, то меняем его на 7. Остальные 8 в номере не трогаем.. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   if($number[0] == '8') {
      $number[0] = '7';
   }
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. репы пока нет.

Comment: @najort да не в репутации дело :-) мне гораздо приятнее знать, что всё получилось.

Comment: но это очень-очень странный вопрос))